# Button size varies in iphone 4 and iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have one project where there is one button.
Which seems so big in iphone 4 as per the size in iphone 4 resolution
and same button looks small in iphone6 as per  the size of the iphone 6 resolution.
I had used autolayout.
But is there any solution to manage it by autolayout or constraint.
Instead of managing size i.e hieght and width programmatically ?

Comment: you can take 3 same buttons as 1x, 2x , 3x that can easily manage your button size or handle size in different iphones

Comment: give aspect ratio to the button with the superview. it will change size according to the superview..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage size of your button, with the ratio of iPhone/iPad screen,

First you need to set equal width and height constraint to your button in storyboard.

Then in code, you have to add two IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint and connect them to respective constraint in storyboard, then update yourButtonWidthConstrant.constant and yourButtonHeightConstrant.constant from code according to the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Give that button an equal width constraint with its super view.
Select that equal width constraint and give multiplier value as (width of button)/(width of superview)
then give aspect ratio to the button.

Now the width of button varies with the width of device and height will change in proportion with its width.

I use this method and it works good.